# Restore iTunes 12 without losing song ratings

Tags: itunes, backup, macos, id3-tag

iTunes has been acting up lately (album cover disappears, glitches when adding ID3-less tracks), and I want to erase my Library and re-add manually my music to iTunes. I know some data is written in the ID3 tag of the song (Song Name, Album Name, etc), but not my personal ratings.

**How can I erase and re-add my albums to iTunes without losing data such as Lyrics or Ratings (Stars/Hearts)?**

[image]

Comment: iTunes track sdef includes a 'loved' field, so you could write an Applescript to pull that info out before you do the rebuild, and put it back in afterwords. I did this back in 2011 or so, but I'm not even seeing the old code on my SSD. You might check out https://dougscripts.com/itunes/index.php to see if he has a current script that'll do this.

Comment: Is it the one called "copy track info tag?"

Comment: The **rating** and **loved** properties of each track